# Idiomatic Ruby: data structure transformation

Tags: ruby, data-structures, hash, merge, transformation

What's the "Rubyist" way to do the following data structure transformation:

I have

```
    incoming = [ {:date => 20090501, :width => 2}, 
                 {:date => 20090501, :height => 7}, 
                 {:date => 20090501, :depth => 3}, 
                 {:date => 20090502, :width => 4}, 
                 {:date => 20090502, :height => 6}, 
                 {:date => 20090502, :depth => 2},
               ]
```

and I want to collapse these by :date, to end up with

```
    outgoing = [ {:date => 20090501, :width => 2, :height => 7, :depth => 3},
                 {:date => 20090502, :width => 4, :height => 6, :depth => 2},
               ]
```

An array of arrays would also be fine at the last step, provided that the columns are in the same order in each row.  Also, importantly, I do not know all the hash keys in advance (that is, I do not know :width, :height, or :depth -- they could be :cats, :dogs, and :hamsters).

Comment: If order is important, than you *want* arrays. Relying on Hash order is a bad idea and only works at all in Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Yeah, but if I keep the hash structure, then my keys will give me whatever ordering I need.  I just made the extra comment about ordering for the array of arrays, because there's no way to put it back together after the fact if I have an unordered sub-array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If using Ruby 1.8.7 or Ruby 1.9+ the following code reads well:

```
incoming.group_by{|hash| hash[:date]}.map do |_, hashes| 
  hashes.reduce(:merge)
end
```

The underscore in the block attributes (_, hashes)  indicates that we don't need/care about that particular attribute.

#reduce is an alias for #inject, which is used to *reduce* a collection into a single item. In the new Ruby versions it also accepts a symbol, which is the name of the method used to do the *reduction*.

It starts out by calling the method on the first item in the collection with the second item as the argument. It then calls the method again on the result with the third item as the argument and so on until there are no more items.

```
[1, 3, 2, 2].reduce(:+) => [4, 2, 2] => [6, 2] => 8
```

Comment: nice... didn't knew about the group_by feature in recent rubies.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one liner :)

```
incoming.inject({}){ |o,i| o[i[:date]]||=[];o[i[:date]]<<i;o}.map{|a| a[1].inject(){|o,i| o.merge(i)}}
```

But actually the previous post is more clear, and might be faster too.

EDIT: with a bit of optimization:

```
p incoming.inject(Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=[]}){ |o,i| o[i[:date]]<<i;o}.map{|a| a[1].inject(){|o,i| o.merge(i)}}
```

Comment: Explanation: first inject creates a hash with the dates as keys and an array of the hashes as values. Then the map will merge all of these hashes into one.

Answer (score 2):

A concise solution:

```
incoming = [ {:date => 20090501, :width => 2}, 
             {:date => 20090501, :height => 7}, 
             {:date => 20090501, :depth => 3}, 
             {:date => 20090502, :width => 4}, 
             {:date => 20090502, :height => 6}, 
             {:date => 20090502, :depth => 2},
           ]

temp = Hash.new {|hash,key| hash[key] = {}}
incoming.each {|row| temp[row[:date]].update(row)}
outgoing = temp.values.sort {|*rows| rows[0][:date] <=> rows[1][:date]}
```

The only thing that's at all tricky here is the Hash constructor, which allows you to supply a block that's called when you access a nonexistent key. So I have the Hash create an empty Hash for us to update with the values we're finding. Then I just use the date as the hash keys, sort the hash values by date and we're transformed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
incoming = [ {:date => 20090501, :width => 2}, 
                 {:date => 20090501, :height => 7}, 
                 {:date => 20090501, :depth => 3}, 
                 {:date => 20090502, :width => 4}, 
                 {:date => 20090502, :height => 6}, 
                 {:date => 20090502, :depth => 2},
               ]

# Grouping by `:date`
temp = {}

incoming.each do |row|
    if temp[row[:date]].nil? 
        temp[row[:date]] = []
    end

    temp[row[:date]] << row
end      

# Merging it together
outcoming = []         

temp.each_pair do |date, hashlist|
    res = {}
    hashlist.each do |hash|
        res.merge!(hash)
    end
    outcoming << res 
end
```

For information concerning the `hash`-members, see [this page](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002905)

When ordering is important, you must use jagged arrays:

```
incoming = [ {:date => 20090501, :width => 2}, 
                 {:date => 20090501, :height => 7}, 
                 {:date => 20090501, :depth => 3}, 
                 {:date => 20090502, :width => 4}, 
                 {:date => 20090502, :height => 6}, 
                 {:date => 20090502, :depth => 2},
               ]

# Grouping by `:date`
temp = {}

incoming.each do |row|
    if temp[row[:date]].nil? 
        temp[row[:date]] = []
    end
    key = row[:date]
    row.delete :date
    temp[key] << row
end      

# Merging it together
outcoming = []         

temp.each_pair do |date, hashlist|
    res = [:date, date]
    hashlist.each do |hash|
        hash.each_pair {|key, value| res << [key, value] }
    end
    outcoming << res
end
```